# Loading text file and then printing it

Tags: javascript, filereader

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput")
    let displayArea = document.getElementById("displayArea")

    fileInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        let file = fileInput.files[0];

        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            displayArea.innerText = e.target.result;
        };

        reader.onerror = (e) => {
            console.error("File could not be read! Code " + e.target.error.code);
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);

        console.log(displayArea.innerText);
    });
}, false);

<input type="file" id="fileInput">
<div id="displayArea"></div>
```

`div` contains the text, but `console.log` gets `<empty string>`.

I think it logs before `reader.onload`.

I tried to do something with `async` and `await`, but without any success.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Move console.log into reader.onload after div innerText set

Comment: `onload` is a callback function. Is executed when the reader loads (hence the onload name). That means that the `console.log` is executed before the onload callback is executed. Being the code before don't means that runs before. It runs when it has to run. That's keyword here to look up in Google is `asyncrhonous`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Move `console.log(displayArea.innerText);` into the `onload` callback.